# mysql-connector-java のバージョンの確認方法

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, homebrew

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31174882/1979953
に`mysql-connector-java`が古いためにJavaとの接続に失敗したとあるのですが、この`mysql-connector-java`はどのように確認するのでしょうか？上記リンクにはXMLらしきものが書いてますが、どこかに設定ファイルが存在するのでしょうか？ Mac に brewで入れたMySQLを使っています。

Spring Bootを使っています。
そのSpringからMySQLに接続できなくて困っているMacが少し古いのですが、他の正常に動いているマシーンでも`mysql-connector-java`を自分でダウンロードしてきた記憶はありません。
（ターミナルでmysqlコマンドを使いポート番号を指定して接続できることは確認済み。その他GUIクライアントでも接続できることを確認済み）

（`mysql-connector-java`がbrewのMySQLの時点で入っているのか、Spring Bootがいい感じに依存関係をみて入れているのは理解できていません）

（MySQのバージョンは5.6.26です。接続を成功させるために試行錯誤したいので、おそらく近いうちにバージョンは上げてしまいます。もしくはMariaDBに変えます）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven(`pom.xml`)/Gradle(`build.gradle*`)で指定したものが利用されます。

それら構成ファイルを直接見るか(質問文のリンク先はMavenの`pom.xml`です)、

```
mvn dependency:tree
gradle dependencies
```

コマンドを実行することでプロジェクトが利用しているモジュールを出力できます。